# Comment Author details are not displayed when comment is submitted by REST API

Tags: views, comments, 8

Currently I am using the following Drupal 8 REST method

POST: http://example.com/entity/comment

Content-type: application/json

```
    {
      "entity_id":[{"target_id":123}],
      "entity_type":[{"value":"node"}],
      "comment_type":[{"target_id":"comment"}],
      "field_name":[{"value":"comment"}],
      "subject":[{"value":"Goodbye World"}],
      "comment_body":[
        {"value":"<p>See you later!</p>","format":"basic_html"}
      ]
    }
```

201 - Created

This I referred from this link https://goo.gl/kXCS8Q
The comment is getting created properly but the Comment's Author Details are not been displayed.

Can anyone tell what else I need to send the parameters for Comments?

Comment: maybe try to specify the user ID: `"uid": [ { "target_id": 1 }]`

Comment: Thanks @JohnReyTanquinco It worked, but now it only gives me only the User ID for first name, last name and User Image what parameters do I need to add?

Comment: Try to add those fields in your view or manage field or whatever way you want(to your case in comment) then do call a GET method, you will see each params you need.

Comment: Glad it works. Feel free to accept my answer if it fits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the solution here.

To get or determine a specific REST parameters, add these fields in your view or content manage fields, then try to access it by running the GET method command. It will show up all parameters of the content/node you need.

Then you can use POST method when planning to update or creating node of your need.